# Allow but Discourage swap on Ubuntu

Tags: ram, swap

There are copious posts on disabling Ubuntu swap completely. Is it possible to tell Ubuntu to allow but discourage swap usage?

I've installed Xubuntu on a laptop with 1Gb ram and a small SSD, turning it into a Samba server. In a worst case scenario free memory still can fit all data from a swap file:

```
~$ free -m
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           991        696        294         17         66        175
-/+ buffers/cache:        454        536
Swap:         1952        107       1845
```

I want to discourage discourage swap when free memory is available, because swap does a lot of IO writes that degrade SSD quickly.

Is it possible to prioritize RAM over swap or the choice is limited to "swap on/off"? What side effects if any does it cause?

---

Thank you for pointing out existing answers they are relevant but hard to find. User must know 90% of the answer to search for "how to configure swappiness".
Question answered. Hope this question header helps indexing.

Comment: Search for "swappiness" on askubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a pretty old SSD, halfway modern SSDs can handle lots of writes, so you don’t really need to do anything if you have a halfway modern SSD.

If you still want to reduce swapping, reduce `swappiness` (minimum value on modern Linux is `1`, not `0`, if you want to go all out, though `10` is the recommended minimum and `60` is the Ubuntu default). This can slow things down greatly (to the point that the system can freeze up for quite a while if under heavy memory pressure) when swapping finally begins, since little to nothing will be swapped out ahead of time.

To set `swappiness`, replace `10` below with the `swappiness` you want, `1` to `100`, where lower values swap less frequently. Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and run:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Now, add a line to the bottom (or if there’s already a `vm.swappiness` line, edit that):

```
vm.swappiness = 10
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano`. Close the terminal window.